# Как узнать какие порты открыты на локальном компьютере?

Tags: c#

Как узнать какие порты открыты на моем девайсе, программным методом C#

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/570461/7099599

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способы проверки портов попытками коннекта могут быть ненадежными или занимать слишком много времени, особенно при проверке нескольких портов. К тому же, приложения могут слушать только определенные ip-адреса, и не слушать при этом 127.0.0.1, что приведет к негативному результату при попытке подключения.

В C# есть [стандартный способ получения списка активных TCP Listners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipglobalproperties(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
    .GetActiveTcpListeners();
```

Работает достаточно быстро, результат можно отфильтровать по нужному порту / ip.

```
var isPortBusy = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()
    .GetActiveTcpListeners().Any(l => l.Port == 80);
```

Comment: @AlehaAleha ок. я чуть сократил ответ :)

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант прозвонить в диапазоне от [`IPEndPoint.MinPort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.minport(v=vs.110).aspx) до [`IPEndPoint.MaxPort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.maxport(v=vs.110).aspx). По идее, это займет очень много времени...

Функция проверки открыт ли порт:

```
public bool CheckIfPortIsOpen(int port)
{
    try
    {
        using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
        {
            tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Советую обернуть метод в таску, ибо он может быть продолжительным.

---

Думаю, если за секунд 5 коннекшн не установился, то и смысла нет ждать. Поэтому могу предложить следующую реализацию:

```
public async Task<bool> CheckIfPortIsOpenAsync(int port)
{
    var connectTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
            {
                tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", port);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });

    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
    var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);

    return firstFinishedTask == connectTask ? connectTask.Result : false;
}
```